C++ truncating float value
I'm completely new to programming and C++. I'm doing some practice exercises but I noticed when I add large numbers together the output value is truncated as if it's an int data type even though both data types are float. Can someone please explain why this happens or if it's something I'm doing wrong?
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    float num1 = 253654.69;
    float num2 = 362554.73;
    float num3 = num1 + num2;
    std::cout << num3;
    return 0;
}
// all variables are float type
// expected output = 616209.42 but value is being truncated = 616209


Related/dupe: cout << double not printing decimal places. cout's default precision for float is 6, which is cutting off the decimal value.  Use std::fixed and std::setprecision to increase the precision to display more digits. Or use double instead, which has a higher precision.

For floating numbers the type to use is double. float is smaller and has a precision of only 6 digits (15 with double). And by default only 6 first digits are displayed, you can use @RemyLebeau comment to display more significant digits.

Also, you can only count on having about 6 decimal digits of precision in a float.  (FLT_DIG specifically, by contract)

expected output = 616209.42 you should not expect that.  Floating point numbers are not exact.
